Creating a Report from selected features, using Attribute Table fields in QGIS
I am using QGIS 3 and I need to get reports from a selected feature of shapefile. This report has to include all the information of Attribute Table and if it is possible to show the selected polygon and the basemap that I use.
I am using a shapefile which includes only polygons, and the records are more than 3000.

I suppose, you want a map, showing the single feature, and all of its attributes? Because "report" sounds more like "long text".

I want most a report, because I manage properties. So, when I select a polygon, which represents a property, I want to show me firstly the data of attribute table and if its possible a small map of a polygon

Please provide an example of what you want to achieve. The term "report" is too ambiguous.

ok I made an image. Imagine this in A4 paper. https://ibb.co/h23kgcy

So... you want a map, showing a single feature, and some of its attributes. Have you read up on creating layouts and altas?

The point is that I need something to give me the information of the selected shapefile directly, without having to create layout every time. I need the map just supportively

Are you asking how to use the identify tool?

No, printable information I mean, a form. Select a polygon and directly take the elements of Attribute Table in a printable form, including a small map

So, a layout. Which can be saved as a template or as a part of the project - no need to recreate it everytime. To be fair, updating the attribute table can be clumbersome, but using an atlas this should work out fine.

My solution does not include tools in QGIS but it can be applied via IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) or online Platforms (such as Jupyter Notebooks or Google Collab). I highly recommend the latter ones if you are not into programming.
The dataset I used is  hybas_eu_lev03_v1c.shp and can be found here: https://www.hydrosheds.org/products/hydrobasins if you want to reproduce the results.
Code
# install the libraries
!pip install geopandas
!pip install python-docx 

# import the libraries
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from docx import Document

data = gpd.read_file(r"F:\Tutorials\gis_exchange\hybas_eu_lev01-12_v1c\hybas_eu_lev03_v1c.shp")

# I will use the first 5 rows of the DataFrame data.
data_head = data.head(5)

# creation of images
for idx, row in data_head.iterrows():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # Plot the entire GeoDataFrame with a light color
    data.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgrey')
    # Highlight the individual feature
    data.iloc[[idx]].plot(ax=ax, color='red')
    # Customize the plot with title, labels, etc.
    ax.set_title(f'Feature {idx}')
    plt.savefig(str(row['HYBAS_ID'])+'.png')


data_cols = data_head.columns.to_list()

# creation of the report for each feature  
for index, row in data_head.iterrows():
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading('Details', 0)
    p = document.add_paragraph('The details of the feature are presented below:')

    table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
    first_row = table.rows[0].cells
    first_row[0].text = 'Field'
    first_row[1].text = 'Value'
    table.style = 'Table Grid'
    
    # I removed teh last one since it was about geometryy and is not useful
    for i in range(len(data_cols) -1):
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        row_cells[0].text = str(data_cols[i])
        row_cells[1].text = str(row[data_cols[i]])
    
    print(str(row['HYBAS_ID'])+'.png')
    document.add_picture(str(row['HYBAS_ID'])+'.png')

    # export document
    output_file = f'passenger_{row["HYBAS_ID"]}.docx'
    print(output_file)
    document.save(output_file)



Explanation
At the beginning, the code installs the necessary libraries, geopandas for spatial data manipulation and python-docx for creating Word documents. The script then reads a shapefile into a GeoDataFrame and extracts the first five rows to save time (in your case, will skip this row). For each of these rows, it generates a plot highlighting the specific feature against a backdrop of the entire dataset, saving each plot as a PNG file named after the feature's unique identifier.
Following this, the code prepares a Word document for each feature, which includes a heading, a paragraph, and a table listing all attribute fields except for the geometry. The relevant plot is also inserted into the document. Each document is then saved with a filename derived from the feature's unique identifier.
Outputs
The provided code saves the output files in the same directory where the code is executed.

Example of the report

Last but not least, it is important to note that alternative solutions for similar tasks could be implemented using PyQGIS, a Python library for working with QGIS.

Yes, this is what I want. Thank you very much Ilias.
